# SSH to OpenConnect Client

Tags: vpn, openconnect

When using Cisco AnyConnect on a mac, I can ssh to my mac via the VPN dhcp address provided.  On my Ubuntu 17.10 box using OpenConnecct, the connections are refused.  Using Wireshark, I can see vpn0 send a RST packet.  ICMP (pings) are allowed however.  How can I configure my Ubuntu to allow ssh to the vpn0 interface?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Check your firewall. It could be that port 23 is not open.
2. openssh isn't installed by default on Ubuntu, nor is telnet. If you want to install them, `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and `sudo apt-get install telnetd`
3. Even if ssh is installed, the root user is generally denied access to ssh. Try creating an unprivileged user and then see if you can ssh in as that user. If so, it is a permission issue. You need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add `PermitRootLogin yes`